# Water droplets through LVP in basement

Tags: concrete, basement, flooring, waterproofing

About two years ago I placed LifeProof LVP in the basement on the concrete floor. Today, after about two days of rain, I noticed some droplets between some of the seems in the room with the LVP. Not everywhere mostly in one small area and its just some droplets, not a lot of water.

A few questions:

1. Should I have put an underlayment down for moisture? LifeProof says that their LVP has underlayment, so I didn't but now I'm thinking I should've put Dricore down beforehand.
2. Should I rip out all the existing flooring and replace with underlayment + new flooring? Or since this flooring is "waterproof" can I just keep it as is?

Thanks for the help

Comment: I think the manufacturer would be in a better position to answer your concerns. There could be some warranty issues that could work n your favor.

Comment: Is the flooring water proof or water resistant?  Water proof flooring should not be damaged by water.  Water resistant might be.

Comment: @crip659 I researched the Q&A for the planks and it turns out the top is waterproof but the bottom is not water resistant or water proof.

Comment: Could be humidity

Answer (score 2):

Flooring guy here.

Answer; Your flooring is okay.
The subfloor should be able to handle some drops of water. If there's a LOT (like a gallon plus, or a constant, leaky pipe) of water, it's probably worth checking the subfloor for water damage.

LVP is a waterproof product, as in, it's fine if it gets wet. But most LVPs don't have watertight joints and won't prevent water from going through like sheet vinyl or linoleum would.
There's a lot of newer laminates like Mohawk Revwood, Engineered Timberstep and some others that have watertight locking systems. You have to caulk the perimeters but they do keep the water from going through to the subfloor like you're running into.

Comment: Looking back, looks like I misunderstood the question. If the water is coming from underneath, it would be an issue with the waterproof laminate products. You can treat the floor with different primers and underlayment options to help. Hope you got it sorted out alright.